# Control the settings of two simultaneous ui-bootstrap modals?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two UI-Bootstrap (AngularUI) modals running at the same time. What I want, is when the user hits the "esc" key, only the top-most modal exits, and the remaining modal's settings change so that it can now be closed by pressing "esc".

Currently, if I have both modals running at the same time and hit 'esc', both modals close, but the backdrop is still over the entire screen.

So is there any way to dynamically control the settings of these modals? I've tried changing the settings during the opening sequence of the second modal, which did change the settings, but the setting wasn't applied.

JSFiddle coming soon.